# What is the best process to test Pantone formulas for plastic before production?

Tags: print-design, workflow, pantone

We've been tasked with designing a plastic straw that will have a printed logo.

The Pantone colour of the plastic straw (320 C) and the printed logo (7700 C) have been provided by the client, although they have only ever used these Pantone colours for their screen and print mediums - they haven't ever used these for producing plastic or printing on plastic.

Can anyone suggest a process to test our designs using Laser or Inkjet printers before it goes to production? Which colour books and tool would be most useful?

Comment: By production... what do you mean? Offset print? Flexography? Spot colors? Color selection?

Comment: Ask your product manufacturer about colour reproduction/proofing, and how you should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

When producing plastic straws, the plastic itself is made in a color of your choice (it`s not printed on it). Colors used for that are defined in a RAL color chart. The number od available colors is much smaller than Pantone, so you will have to find the closest color that fits your needs.

Manufacturer usually has the color samples to choose from, so you`ll probably have to start from that and ask them if they can make you a color proof on material color of your choice. In any case, some compromise will probably have to me made.

Comment: Although RAL certainly targets plastics, there is a range of Pantone colors for plastics as well. What one really needs to do is ask the manufacturer of straws as to their color capabilities.